# Change in native platform support for Android Application

Tags: android, apk

Recently, I had fixed bug for Android application I was working on it but my **Native Support** increase from 4 to 7 at Play Store. Here is the image of previous version image that shows number of Native Platform Support **CPU Architecture**

[image: Production Build which is already on Play store]

Now when I updated new Android APK for **Alpha Testing** which consist of bug fixed but my **Native Platform** support increases, here is a link of **Alpha Update to Play Store**

[image: Alpha Release of Application with 7 Native Platform Support]

I am using third party library
 ** compile 'pl.droidsonroids.gif:android-gif-drawable:1.2.8'** in my application.

**Can anyone tell me why this happens?**
**As I have not made any changes in build.gradle file.**

Comment: Any update on this?

Comment: @ShailendraMadda Nothing much I need to exclude some arch in Gradle file

Comment: Okay, I resolved it now, here is my fault and solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66642569/2462531