# Android how to support all native platforms in Google Play store always showing 138

Tags: android, android-multiple-apk

I am trying to release an APK for internal testing. I don't know why it is only showing supported devices as 138 only. How to fix it to support all the devices.

[image]

This is my app-level `build.gradle`

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 29
    buildToolsVersion '29.0.3'
    defaultConfig {

        applicationId "com.test.myapp"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode 3
        versionName "prod_0.1"

        testInstrumentationRunner 'androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner'

        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
        multiDexEnabled true
        generatedDensities = []

        javaCompileOptions {
            annotationProcessorOptions {
                includeCompileClasspath = true
            }
        }
    }
    // Flag notifies aapt to keep the attribute IDs around
    aaptOptions {
        //  additionalParameters "--no-version-vectors"
        cruncherEnabled = false
    }
    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/services/javax.annotation.processing.Processor'
    }
    lintOptions {
        checkReleaseBuilds false
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
        debug {
            minifyEnabled false
        }
    }
   
    dexOptions {
        jumboMode true
        javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, I fixed the issue by disabling this line in the Manifest file.

```
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.wifi.rtt" />
```